# How to use THAT and WHO

Tags: relative-pronouns, ellipsis

I have some doubts about the usages of That and Who. Sometimes I read sentences such as. "You are someone I love" "You are someone WHO I love" Or "People were asked to describe the qualities they look for in a friend" "People were asked to describe the qualities THAT they look for in a friend"

Why in some of these sentences WHO or THAT are omitted and others are not. Could somebody help me with this? I'll appreciate it! Thanks a million.

Comment: Welcoome to ELL! StackExchange deprecates cross-posting between SE sites, so please delete either this question or the same question on [elu.se].

Answer (score 2):

There are some rules about omitting *relative pronouns* from the sentences. I'll try outlining some of them:

a) Prefer keeping relative pronouns if you are dealing with a *non-defining* clause. For instance, *The girl, **who** is identified as a terrorist, is the one we saw yesterday.* 
  b) It's *okay* if you drop a relative pronoun if you are dealing with a *defining* clause. For instance, *The girl (whom) we saw yesterday is found out to be a terrorist.* 
  c) If a relative pronoun is modifying the *object,* you can drop the relative pronoun. If it's modifying *subject*, avoid removing it.

Other tips found [here](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/relative.htm).

[image]

Additional note: Just to add value to this answer. Though to some using *that* as a relative pronoun referring to a person may look *less human*, it has become quite a common practice.

From the [American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/who-versus-that#sthash.zZJzpPOR.dpuf):

> *It is entirely acceptable to write either the man that wanted to talk to you, or the man who wanted to talk to you.*

Answer (score -2):

"You are someone WHO I love".. you cannot use this sentence to express your love on a person..
You can say "you are the one whom I love" or else you can say "you are among the people whom I love alot"..

If you want to show a person, you can say "I love that person"(informal)
or "He is the person whom I love"(formal)..

----According to the rules of formal grammar, who should be used in the subject position in a sentence, while whom should be used in the object position, and also after a preposition.---

For example:

**Who made this decision?** [here, who is the subject of the sentence]

**Whom do you think we should support?** [here, whom is the object of support]

**To whom do you wish to speak?** [here, whom is following the preposition to]